# Trouble installing Burrows-Wheeler Aligner (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Please bear with me, I'm just getting into using both virtual machines and linux.

I'm having trouble installing BWA ([link](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/)) on my linux virtual machine. I've tried several methods, the most complete directions I've found are from from the medical department at [Cornell](http://icb.med.cornell.edu/wiki/index.php/Elementolab/BWA_tutorial), but I'm probably misunderstanding what they want me to do.

I downloaded the latest version 0.7.9a from sourceforge and moved it into a folder in my home directory. The path to the file is:

```
/home/jp/bwa/bwa-0.7.9a.tar.bz2
```

I then unzipped the file:

```
bunzip2 bwa-0.7.9a.tar.bz2
```

and then un-tared the file:

```
tar xvf bwa-0.7.9a.tar
```

Then I went into the new directory I created:

```
cd bwa-0.7.9a
```

I then used the "make command"

```
make
```

**This is where I get hung up:**

The terminal prints this error:

```
jp@jp-VirtualBox:~/bwa$ cd bwa-0.7.9a
jp@jp-VirtualBox:~/bwa/bwa-0.7.9a$ dir
bamlite.c   bwase.c     bwtsw2_aux.c    kopen.c    NEWS.md
bamlite.h   bwase.h     bwtsw2_chain.c  kseq.h     pemerge.c
bntseq.c    bwaseqio.c  bwtsw2_core.c   ksort.h    QSufSort.c
bntseq.h    bwtaln.c    bwtsw2.h        kstring.c      QSufSort.h
bwa.1       bwtaln.h    bwtsw2_main.c   kstring.h      qualfa2fq.pl
bwa.c       bwt.c       bwtsw2_pair.c   ksw.c      README.md
bwa.h       bwtgap.c    ChangeLog       ksw.h      utils.c
bwa-helper.js   bwtgap.h    COPYING     kthread.c      utils.h
bwamem.c    bwt_gen.c   example.c       kvec.h     xa2multi.pl
bwamem_extra.c  bwt.h       fastmap.c       main.c
bwamem.h    bwtindex.c  is.c        Makefile
bwamem_pair.c   bwt_lite.c  kbtree.h        malloc_wrap.c
bwape.c     bwt_lite.h  khash.h     malloc_wrap.h
jp@jp-VirtualBox:~/bwa/bwa-0.7.9a$ make
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -O2 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DUSE_MALLOC_WRAPPERS  utils.c -o utils.o
utils.c:33:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [utils.o] Error 1
jp@jp-VirtualBox:~/bwa/bwa-0.7.9a$
```

I'm not sure how to handle this error. Could you guys provide any insight as to what needs to be done?

A second question I have pertaining to the next steps in the instructions provided by the Cornell website. It reads,

> "Add bwa to your PATH by editing ~/.bashrc and adding

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bwa-0.5.9"
```

I've located .bashrc in my home directory (I can view it by using ls -a in command line, or using ctrl+h in the explorer). I'm not sure how to go about editing the file to include the appropriate line of code, i.e. do I just paste it anywhere in that file?

I've interpreted their directions to mean I should add something along the lines of

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jp/bwa/bwa-0.7.9a
```

But I'm not sure if that's correct.

---

I have installed a much earlier version (0.5) through the following command.

```
get-apt install bwa
```

but, I do not want to use an outdated version of this program.

Any help you guys would be able to give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

---

Host Machine OS: Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) (Service Pack 1)
Virtual Machine Software: Oracle VirtualBox Version 4.3.12
Guest Machine OS: Ubuntu 14.02 (32 bit (I couldn't get the 64 bit to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the ZLIB header files.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

<strike>Or maybe:</strike>

```
sudo apt-get install zlib-dev
```

The first should be the right one, but I don't have a Ubuntu machine to test it on.

Hope this fixes your problem!

**EDIT**
Created a Ubuntu VM and verified that **`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` is the correct command.**

Comment: This worked for me. I'm sorry I forgot to make this as answered!

Comment: @jrp355 Thanks for remembering! :)